# VSCode IntelliSense: How to resolve path aliases in SCSS module imports

Tags: css, typescript, visual-studio-code, sass, intellisense

In VS Code I would like to be able to jump into other SCSS modules using path aliases as defined in `tsconfig.json`.

Our Webpack/Vite build setup works fine (e.g. via `sass-loader/options/sassOptions/includePaths` Webpack config). And I also know in PHP Storm this is possible by setting the given path to resolve as a `Resource Directory`.

However, so far I was not able to find a setting, a plugin or configuration that could make this work for VS Code IntelliSense.

**Folder Structure**

- modules

  - components

    - Component.tsx
  - styles

    - styles1.module.scss
    - styles2.module.scss
- tsconfig.json

**styles1.module.scss**

```
.class1 {
  display: flex;
}
```

**Component.tsx - Import works fine**

```
import styles1 from '@/styles/styles1.module.scss'; // import + intellisense works fine
import styles2 from '@/styles/styles2.module.scss';
```

**styles2.module.scss - IntelliSense does not work**

```
@import '@/styles/styles1.module.scss';
```

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "modules",
    "paths": {
      "@/styles/*": ["styles/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Any help appreciated! Thanks.

[image: VS Code IntelliSense Error]

Comment: did you figure out how to solve this? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: any luck to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

just use alias-tool and Path Autocomplete

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dgeibi.alias-tool
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ionutvmi.path-autocomplete

**.vscode/settings.json**

```json
{
    "alias-tool.mappings": {
        "@": "${folder}"
    },
    "path-autocomplete.pathMappings": {
         "@": "${folder}"
    }
}
```

Comment: You are awesome. This really works! I don't even need the path-autocomplete extension. I just installed the alias tool extension and added it to my VSCode json config.
 "alias-tool.mappings": {
  "@": "${folder}",
  "@scss": "${folder}/src/scss",
  "@assets": "${folder}/src/assets",
 },

Answer (score -1):

I try serval ways：

- remove `.next` and restart server
- remove `node_modules` and install, restart server
- Finally I just restart vscode and it work.

Comment: url aliases are not exclusive to nextjs